# How to drop columns after joining to temp table?

Tags: sql, join, temp-tables

I have two tables which I am trying to join on the column `transcript_id` so that I can attach a second identifier `gene_name` to my actual data. In my first table, there are many different rows with the same `transcript_id` because each transcript is made up of many exons (which I'm not interested in for this analysis). I got around this by making a temp table to only select distinct transcript_id values:

```
WITH tempID AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT(transcript_id), gene_id 
    FROM `lab-stuff.rna_seq.RN6`
)
```

Then I joined the temp table 'tempID' to the file that actually has my data:

```
SELECT *
FROM `lab-stuff.rna_seq.1_1_1` AS data_111
RIGHT JOIN tempID
ON data_111.gene_id = tempID.gene_id
ORDER BY TPM DESC
```

This produces the data that I actually wanted, but the gene_id column is now duplicated in the table which annoys me on a spiritual level:

| gene_id | gene_name | FPKM | TPM | transcript_id | gene_id_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name of a gene | different name | numbers | numbers | transcript ID | name of a gene |

Is there a way to drop the extra column after the join?

Comment: of course, there is a way. Replace * with names of the columns you need.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT transcript_id, gene_id ..` to make code clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Yep! You are grabbing `gene_id` from two tables: the first one on your CTE, and the second one on your JOIN with the table `rna_seq.1_1_1` again.

By doing this:

```
WITH tempID AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      transcript_id, 
      gene_id 
    FROM 
      `lab-stuff.rna_seq.RN6`
)
SELECT 
  data_111.gene_id,
  data_111.gene_name,
  data_111.FPKM,
  data_111.TPM,
  tempID.transcript_id
FROM 
  `lab-stuff.rna_seq.1_1_1` AS data_111
RIGHT JOIN 
  tempID ON data_111.gene_id = tempID.gene_id
ORDER BY 
  TPM DESC
```

You are selecting which `gene_id` to show, which in this case is the one from the table called `data_111`

Comment: thanks for the help! I had tried this earlier but forgotten to include the column from my temp table, doh